# Swift $sort order for BSON RealmSwift document

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb, sorting, realm

TLDR:
**how can I write a document with a definitive order for the key value pairs to pass as key to the $sort stage?**

I stumbled across very strange behaviour in my aggregate query that I am running in Swift (using RealmSwift package) through:

```swift
db.collection(withName: "Example")..aggregate(pipeline: aggregatePipeline) { ... }
```

This is the stage that is behaving very strangely:

```swift
let aggregatePipeline: [Document] = [
                [
                    "$sort": [ "seen": 1 , "score": -1, "_id": -1 ]
                ]
]
```

The results I get are sorted by these three keys, but in seemingly arbitrary sorting order each time I run the query. So sometimes the "seen" sorting is prioritised (as it should be) but sometimes it sorts first by "_id", or "score". When I print the stage right after defining it by running:

```swift
print(aggregatePipeline[0])
```

I do see a the probable reason for those odd results...
first run:

```swift
["$sort": Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.document(["_id": Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.int64(-1)), "seen": Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.int64(1)), "score": Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.int64(-1))]))]
```

second run:

```swift
["$sort": Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.document(["seen": Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.int64(1)), "score": Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.int64(-1)), "_id": Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.int64(-1))]))]
```

how can I write this query with a definitive sorting order? Or more simply: **how can I write a document with a definitive order for the key value pairs to pass as key to the $sort stage?** I found nothing in the relevant [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) or especially [this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/app-services/mongodb-remote-access/) where it should definitely be stated how this could be accomplished, since this would be the most sensible way, but obviously is the wrong way of doing it.

Comment: This is a good question and I was able to duplicate the issue; one thing to note is that Document is a dictionary so its contents will be unordered. However, using the [mongodb playground](https://mongoplayground.net) the issue shows itself there as well. I created a dataset with 5 entries, each having two properties `name` and `num` with name being a string and num being an Int, and then used an aggregate sort as in your question. The results were sometimes sorted by name and sometimes sorted by num. Perhaps we are overlooking something but I would file a bug report on github just in case.

Comment: Perhaps it needs an index (??) something like this `db.collection.createIndex({seen : -1, score : -1})` OR, perhaps aggregate functions cannot be run directly on a collection? They would need to be run on the results set? e.g. do a `find` and then run the aggregate function against those results?